# How can I see which invite link the newcomer came from?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a server have a invite system. When anyone came to my server i want to know who invited this user. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Discord does not allow an endpoint for this. The "best" way would be to fetch the audit logs, then fetch the server invites and compare the codes.